# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Hello I have a wcf service i need to call but it still respond me with error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM, Negotiate'.'

My code looks like below:

Client creation:

```
var binding = CreateBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(_settings.Endpoint);
var client = new VoucherService.VoucherServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
```

Binding:

```
private static BasicHttpBinding CreateBinding()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
        ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 33554432,
        TransferMode= TransferMode.Buffered,
        Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
        {
            Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
            Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
            {
                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm
            }
        }

    };
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 32000;
    return binding;
}
```

and call:

```
var response = client.Send(/*some data*/)
```

There is old .net4 solution i took configuration from. And there it works and i can calls service but in new .net 6 solution with the same configuration i am receiving error like at the top. Can you suggest me anything i can check what else is missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In **.NET 6.0** and above, a **Reference.cs** file is usually generated after the WCF service is called.

In this file there is a self-generated method:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
```

My suggestion is to check if the configuration is the same as the WCF service.

Finally you use the parameterless constructor

```
var client = new VoucherService.VoucherServiceClient();
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late answer. Yes i was aware of this option and yes configuration is the same. Still does not work. I belive that this is connected to the service being created in .net framework. and me using .net6. When i create .net framework solution. Copy paste code then i can connect

Comment: asp.net core's support for it is really poor. **NTLM, Negotiate**: They are the default way of IIS, and you can check the configuration of IIS. In the meantime you can try: **BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly** change to **BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential **.